# measure time of multiple xmlhttprequest javascript

Tags: javascript, xmlhttprequest

I want to measure time of multiple xmlhttprequest in javascript

```
function httpGetAsync(link){
var xmlHttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
xmlHttp.onreadystatechange = function(){ 
    if (xmlHttp.readyState == 4 && xmlHttp.status == 200){            
        var timeFinish=performance.now();
        var timedDiff=timeFinish-timeStart;
        document.getElementById('result').value+=link+" "+timedDiff+"\n";
    }
}
xmlHttp.open("GET", link, true);     
var timeStart=performance.now();    
xmlHttp.send(null);
}
```

call:

```
httpGetAsync(link1);
httpGetAsync(link1);
httpGetAsync(link1);
```

Every next result add response time to previous. So, it's incorrect.
If I am using different links results seems correct.

I declared variables using var timeStart, timeFinish. Did it mean unique function scope for each call?

Comment: Your function and the variable scopes appear to be correct. Can you show the results that you got, and which links you did test? I suspect they are correct, just slower than you did expect.

Comment: Sorry, code is correct. I tested results again and all is correct now